# Reporting services: The execution failed for the shared dataset 'dsDataSetName'

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]I got this error when i clicked on the preview button (Report form) for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

```
An error occurred during local report processing. An error has occurred during report processing. The execution failed for the shared data set 'Dataset name'. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any idea? Wondering whether it is something with shared dataset.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concern, shared data sets are only available on R2. Also, it must me based on a shared data source.

anyway, I don't think it has anything to do with the fact that the dataset is shared. its just part of the message. If you go to the query designer of your dataset and press F5, can you see the results of the query?

Comment: The report has parameters in it but when I click preview it is not asking me to enter those parameters. Wondering if it is that?

Comment: check the default values of the parameters. maybe an invalid cast. I would also remove the parameters from the query to try to isolate the problem

Comment: I just started with reporting services today. Can't seems to be able to edit parameters using the designer but i can see it in the code. How do you edit parameter using the designer?

Comment: there is a parameters folder. look for your parameter, click properties and check the default values tab

Comment: I can't find the parameters folder. Must be missing some windows. Too bad i can't attach a screenshot

Comment: why cant you add a screenshot?

Comment: Edited the questions with screenshot.. Where is the parameter folder? Which windows am i missing?

Comment: no not there.. showing the default 'Report items' and blank 'General' tab

Comment: Now i can see the folder. Also notice, no data is returned using the query designer. The queries used is not exactly sql! SELECT * FROM [Not table name]

Comment: well you should see. maybe thats the source of the problem. what is being resulted on the designer?